# Is there a way to fit two curves exclusively and simultaneously to multiple edges in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have the following edge-detected image:
[edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG9Nu.png)

As you can see, there are two clearly defined lines that make up two sides of an object. I can fit one curve to the entire thing, but how can I perform a curve fitting so that two curves are fit exclusively and simultaneously to such edges, so that I end up with two lines that describe the shape? In other images, the ends may not be discontinuous in this manner.

Is there a good way to specify number of curves to fit to data, like n=2 in this instance, and have it perform a fit where each curve takes into account the other to stay away from it? I have been unable to find similar problems or libraries that can perform something like this.

The two fitted curves in this instance would end up looking like this: [curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JffSx.png)

Comment: What, objectively, do you mean by “curve” that you would “fit to the entire thing”? Or how should a decision be made about how two (or n) “curve”s could be fitted?

Comment: Imagine the edges are taken as data points on a scatter plot. I can use a curve fitting function in numpy or scipy, to fit a polynomial function to the data. However, I want independently two such polynomial functions. If two curves need to be fit, I imagine to make the decision, a regression would need to be performed where curve #1 is initially fit to everything, then outlier points of this are fit to curve #2, then outlier points of curve #2 are used to refit curve #1, and so on until the two curves stabilize. There might be a more intelligent way to do this though, it's just my guess.

Comment: So you imagine a single curve taking this as an x-y plot and fitting a single line from upper right to lower-ish left. How would that look for two curves? Can you add an image with Sketched-on lines for each of these two curves as you imagine they might look?. I’m wondering if you would be better thinning to a centre line and then trying to figure out more complex curve fitting.

Comment: just added a new image for the curves.

Comment: What research have you done - presumably this didn’t turn up anything useful before you took the last resort of asking here, so what did you reject?